# Modulo adder output shows no change

Tags: verilog

The output waveform shows no change in the `sum`, `dif`, `burrow`, and `out`.  Even after increasing delay time, still the output shows no change. This should work like the mod adder like add 10 and 2 and with mod 3 give output zero.

**CODE**

```
module Mod_adder(a,b,p,out);
input [3:0] a;
input [3:0] b;
input [3:0] p;
output [3:0] out;
wire [3:0] sum;
wire cout;
wire burrow;
wire [3:0] dif;
ripple_carry_adder r1(a,b,sum,cout,1'b0);
ripple_carry_adder r2(sum,~p,dif,burrow,1'b1); 
repeat_sum rs1(dif,burrow,sum);
outval o1(sum,burrow,out);
endmodule

module full_adder(in0, in1, cin, out, cout);
input in0, in1, cin;
output out, cout;
assign out = in0 ^ in1 ^ cin;
assign cout = ((in0 ^ in1) & cin) | (in0 & in1);
endmodule


module ripple_carry_adder(in0, in1, out, cout,cin);
input [3:0] in0;
input [3:0] in1;
output [3:0] out;
output cout;
input cin;
wire c1, c2, c3;
full_adder fa0(in0[0], in1[0], cin, out[0], c1);
full_adder fa1(in0[1], in1[1], c1, out[1], c2);
full_adder fa2(in0[2], in1[2], c2, out[2], c3);
full_adder fa3(in0[3], in1[3], c3, out[3], cout);
endmodule

module repeat_sum(dif,burrow,sum);
input [3:0] dif;
input burrow;
output [3:0] sum;
assign sum = (burrow == 1'b0) ? dif:sum;
endmodule

module outval(sum,burrow,out);
input [3:0] sum;
input burrow;
output [3:0] out;
assign out = (burrow == 1'b1) ? sum:out;
endmodule
```

**TEST BENCH**

```
 ` include "MOD_ADDER.V"
   module Mod_adder_tb; 

   reg [3:0] a; 
   reg [3:0] b;
   reg [3:0] p;
   wire [3:0] out;  // wires

 // Instantiate the module to be tested
  Mod_adder MA1(a,b,p,out);

  initial begin    // initial block
   $dumpfile("Test_Full_Adder.vcd");
   $dumpvars(1, MA1);
    a=4'b1010; 
    b=4'b0100; 
    p=4'b0011; 
    #100;
    end // end of initial block
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 major problems.

Your `out` testbench signal is unknown (`X`) because of driver contention.  For example, the `sum` signal in `Mod_adder` has multiple drivers: from the `r1` instance and from the `rs1` instance.  The `out` output of `r1` and the `sum` output of `rs1` are both driving the `sum` wire.  You should not drive the same signal from 2 different module instances.  You could rename one of the `sum` signals to something unique, like `sum_rs1` and declare a new `wire`.

```
wire [3:0] sum, sum_rs1;
```

Also, you have combinational feed back loops.  For example:

```
assign out = (burrow == 1'b1) ? sum:out;
```

The `out` signal should not be on both the LHS and RHS of a continuous assignment.